# How to identify the encryption in packet data using OLLYDBG

Tags: encryption, decryption, packet

I've been slowly learning the processes of packet decryption over the last 6 or so months, and it's been slow progress.

I've found the winsock2 send function in OllyDbg, and I'm using [this tutorial](http://blog.extendedgames.com/2012/09/finding-gamesend-and-game-crypt.html) to work through what encryption is being used - screen of the location;

[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/2j29mro.jpg]

I'm now about 20,000 feet out of my depth. What I'm hoping to do is figure out the encryption used and then just packet sniff a whole bunch of packets so I can figure out the kind of data being sent etc. (please poke wholes in this plan if you see them!). If anyone can look at the print screen and just 'see' the encryption that would be great, if not any advice on what to do next would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: See [this](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/8821/2354), might help. If you are unfamiliar with the basic terminology and ollydbg in general, do [this](https://tuts4you.com/download.php?list.17) :)

Comment: @fraserofsmeg dont u think six months are enough for you to think of another plan ? this happened to me before, and i regret all these months i spent reversing SHA until i realised that SHA is irreversible (smh)

Comment: @DominikAntal - thanks for the closely related link, and the ollydbg tutorials. I'm going to go through these tutorials before I continue!

Comment: @Agawa001 It's not 6 months of man hours - it's a couple of hours every couple of weeks. :) I'm not doing something impossible, I've read enough articles about how other people have done it to know it's certainly doable, there just seems to be a level of knowledge I'm lacking! :D